# Copying the specific patterns from normal file to CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, subprocess

If I have data in a file (my.txt) like below:

```
Version 3.1
# fruitstall name
# first-file
* i fruits friutname N 1 name S
* i fruits  friutname N 1  N 
+ x apple
+ y 1
+ z 23
+ a 51
+ x banana
+ y 2
+ z 68
+ a 27
+ x mango
+ y 3
+ z 46
+ a 49 
+ x orange
+ y 4
+ z 15
+ a 54
+ x butterfruit
+ y 5
+ z 76
+ a 86
```

How can I write this to a CSV file using Python which will be having data like this?

```
apple 1  23 51 
banana 2 68 27
mango 3 46 49
orange 4 15 54
butterfruit 5 76 86
```

I have tried using this:

```
with open(Unzipped_file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
```

After this, can you please suggest how to proceed?

The attached input text in image format as the data above is not formatted properly:

[input.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQjR1.jpg)

The attached output text in image format as the data above is not formatted properly:

[output.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH7jk.jpg)

Comment: Will the lines always alternate between x and y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:  # open file in read mode
    data = {e: [] for e in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']}  # init data dict like this
    data = defaultdict(list)  # or like this. from collections import defaultdict
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # remove new line char
        if line.startswith('+'):  # if line marked with plus
            _, t, v = line.split()  # get 't' (one of x, y, z, a) and v (fruit or num) 
            data[t].append(v)  # append to corresponded list
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:  # open file in write mode
    for x, y, z, a in zip(data['x'], data['y'], data['z'], data['a']):
        f.write('{} {} {} {}\n'.format(x, y, z, a))
```

Comment: An empty line in the input file (excluding its end) would mess everything up.

Comment: can u pls guide furhter on how can i write that to csv file in the format as i mentioned above

Comment: i have some random data in the text file before the below provided data like Version 3.1 # fruitstall name # first-file * i fruits friutname N 1 name S * i fruits friutname N 1 N * i dsclocal TPAUser TPAUser_$dummy N 1 $dummy N + x apple + y 1 + z 23 + a 51 + x banna + y 2 + z 68 + a 27 + x mango + y 3 + z 46 + a 49 + x orange + y 4 + z 15 + a 54 + x butterfruit + y 5 + z 76 + a 86 , because of which it is not able to perform split operation i think , so with this random data in the text file how can i get the solution

Comment: as the above text is not formatted , please find the input and output data like below in the attached image , input.jpeg , ouput.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

```
path = 'Path to Text.txt'
file = open(path, "r") 
lines = " ".join(file.readlines()[5:])
lines = lines.split("+ x")
res = []
for i in lines:
    val = filter(None, i.replace("\n", "").replace("+", "").split(" "))
    if val:
        stringVal = val[0]
        for iVal in val[1:]:
            if iVal.isdigit():
                stringVal += " {}".format(iVal)
        res.append(stringVal)
print res
```

**Result:**

```
['apple 1 23 51', 'banna 2 68 27', 'mango 3 46 49', 'orange 4 15 54', 'butterfruit 5 76 86']
```

Comment: i have some random data in the text file before the below provided data like

Version 3.1
# fruitstall name
# first-file
* i fruits friutname N 1 name S
* i fruits  friutname N 1  N
* i dsclocal TPAUser TPAUser_$dummy N 1 $dummy N

+ x apple
+ y 1
+ z 23
+ a 51
+ x banna
+ y 2
+ z 68
+ a 27
+ x mango
+ y 3
+ z 46
+ a 49 
+ x orange
+ y 4
+ z 15
+ a 54
+ x butterfruit
+ y 5
+ z 76
+ a 86   , because of which it is not able to perform split operation i think , so with this random data in the text file how can i get the solution

Comment: as the above text is not formatted , please find the input and output data like below in the attached image  , input.jpeg , ouput.jpeg

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply , but now one more query i have                                            if i have data like below in list format                                                                           mango x
5 y
orange x
2 y
apple x
6 y                                                                                                                             how can i convert it to csv with                                                                              mango 5
orange 2
apple 6